# How to deserialize Java Optional field with lombok builder?

Tags: java, jackson, option-type, lombok, jackson-databind

I want to deserialize Java Optional field in lombok builder. Below is my code

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AvailabilityResponse.Builder.class)
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with", builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public class AvailabilityResponse {

    private final List<Train> trainDetails;
    private final String name;
    private final Optional<String> detail;

    public static class Builder {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TRAIN")
        private List<Train> trainDetails;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NAME")
        private String name;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DETAIL_TRAIN", isAttribute = true)
        private String detail;

        public AvailabilityResponse build() {
            return new AvailabilityResponse(
                trainDetails, // I have field validation here. if null or empty throwing Exception
                name, // I have field validation here. if null or empty throwing Exception
                Optional.ofNullable(detail)); // This is Optional field
        }
    }   

}
```

If I override the builder method like below, able to deserialize

```
    private Optional<String> name; // this is static builder class field

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DETAIL_TRAIN", isAttribute = true)
        public Builder detail(final String theDetail) {
            this.detail = Optional.ofNullable(theDetail);
            return this;
        }
```

I have used setterPrefix ="with" in @Builder. But if I override the above method with "with" prefix, its not working.

Please someone help me to acheive this

Comment: Show your xml please.

Comment: <AvailabilityResponse DETAIL_TRAIN="bhh"><TRAIN><TRAIN><number>123455</number></TRAIN></TRAIN><NAME>nsmr23</NAME></AvailabilityResponse>
@Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson supports `Optional` using its `jackson-datatype-jdk8` module. You can simply add it to the `<dependencies>` section in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, initialize your mapper as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

That mapper will automatically detect `Optional`s: If the XML field has a value, it will be wrapped in an `Optional`; if the XML field is empty (i.e., `<DETAIL_TRAIN/>`), then the result will be an `Optional.empty()`. (In your case you have an attribute; those cannot be empty.)

Jackson maps fields or attributes that do not exist in the XML to `null` (or, more precisely, it simply does not call the setter, so the field value will still be the default). If you also want to have an empty `Optional` in that case, you need to set the field default to `Optional.empty()` and add a `@Builder.Default` to that field.

Finally, lombok can automatically copy your annotations from the fields to the generated builder. You need to tell lombok which annotations to copy using a `lombok.config` file in your project root containing:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty
config.stopBubbling = true
```

This means you do not need to customize your builder class at all:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AvailabilityResponse.Builder.class)
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with", builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public class AvailabilityResponse {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TRAIN")
    @JsonProperty("TRAIN")
    private final List<Train> trainDetails;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NAME")
    @JsonProperty("NAME")
    private final String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DETAIL_TRAIN", isAttribute = true)
    @JsonProperty("DETAIL_TRAIN")
    @Builder.Default
    private final Optional<String> detail = Optional.empty();
}
```

Note that you also need `@JsonProperty` annotations on your fields due to [a Jackson bug](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/384).

If you want to validate field values, you should do that in the constructor, not in the builder. In this way you'll also catch those instantiations where the builder is not used. To do so, simply implement the all-args constructor yourself; the `build()` method will use it automatically:

```
private AvailabilityResponse(List<Train> trainDetails, String name, Optional<String> detail) {
    this.trainDetails = Objects.requireNonNull(trainDetails);
    this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    this.detail = Objects.requireNonNull(detail);
}
```

I suggest making this constructor `private`, because

- it enforces users of your class to use the builder, and
- it is bad style to have `Optional`s as parameters in your public API.

Comment: I think I found the problem: Jackson does not recognize the `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation when it is placed on the parameter. I think that's a bug in Jackson, because the annotation is allowed on parameters, and it works for `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/384.
Workaround is to also put a @JsonProperty on the field. I updated my answer.

Comment: After adding @JsonProperty it's working. But it's look very odd, because of adding the annotation and property name with two times. Also if I have null in non Optional fields I want to throw IllegalArguementException, for that only I have override static builder class.

Comment: I updated my answer with why you should not validate in the builder, and I describe a solution.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd have to remove the `@Builder.Default` and default value assignment. `@Builder.Default` moves that default value assignment to a separate method anyway, so no assignment to `detail ` has happend when your manual constructor is called.

Comment: I got this error while compile  ** java: constructor AvailabilityResponse in class com.example.AvailabilityResponse cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.List<com.example.Train>,java.lang.String
  found: java.util.List<com.example.Train>,java.lang.String,java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.**  So only I removed @Builder.Default and added Optional field in constructor.

Comment: Of course the definition of your manual all-args constructor must be compatible to the one that lombok would generate, otherwise the generated builder can't call it. There is no need to remove the `@Builder.Default`, but if you check that parameter (and replace it on `null`) in your constructor anyway, it does not hurt to remove it. I again updated my answer.

Comment: it's working but my intelliJ showing error like "cannot assign a value to final variable" in this line  this.detail = detail.  Because we are trying to update the default value.

Comment: That's a probably a bug in the Intellij Lombok plugin. It works in eclipse and in maven. But as I said it doesn't hurt to remove the default.